# div does not shrink when it wraps the text

Tags: flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to build a title-bar layout that has 3 parts:

1. left: a title that may have long text that can be truncated
2. center: a sub-title that should not be truncated but be wrapped to a new line
3. right: a fixed part (e.g. for a menu button)

This basically works, but the centered div does not shrink as expected, so that it wastes some white-space (see red rectangle mark):

[image]

Here is the full [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-angular-material-titlebar?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

relevant HTML:

```html
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
    <mat-card fxFlex>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
            <div class="truncate-line">Long text can be truncated</div>
            <div fxFlex="nogrow" class="action-blurb">multiple lines</div>
            <div fxFlex="none" class="action-blurb">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

related css:

```css
.truncate-line {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Since `nogrow` is the same as `flex: 0 1 auto` (which is: grow=0, shrink=1, base=auto), I'd expect the centered div to shrink when needed, but it doesn't.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some frustrating hours of research it turned out that [angular flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) has lots of issues, especially related to the flex-basis and min/max-width: [#748](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/748), [#438](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/438), [#689](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/689), [#737](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/737), [#729](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/729), [#884](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/884)

My conclusion to not to use `fxFlex` at all, but rely on the css flex properties.
With pure css it's easy to do what I expect: [Fixed Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-angular-material-titlebar-fixed)

[image]

Relevant code for the middle item:

```html
<div style="background-color: orange; flex: 1 1 70px; min-width: 60px">multiple lines</div>
```